# How do I edit the text in data-reactid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The html goes like this:

```
<div id="AAAA" class="BBBB" tabindex="0" data-reactid="1005">
       <div class="CCCC" data-reactid="1006">
              <!--react-text: 1007 --->
                 Choose one
             <!--/react-text-->
       </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use js to access and edit the text "choose one"?

Comment: See this link http://jsfiddle.net/jatin146/2HXAQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-reactid="1006"]').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

### You May use simple jQuery to change Text of following div

```js
var data = $(".CCCC").text("Updated text .... :)");
//alert(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="AAAA" class="BBBB" tabindex="0" data-reactid="1005">
       <div class="CCCC" data-reactid="1006">
              <!--react-text: 1007 --->
                 Choose one
             <!--/react-text-->
       </div>
</div>
```